# nuget - How to get a project item in a sub folder in powershell script

Tags: powershell, nuget

I'm trying to write a nuGet installer powershell script to copy an executable to the output folder when the project is compiled (C# assembly).

Looking at examples I have managed to get this far but obviously the $file is NULL.

What should I be doing to get access to the file?

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

# $project = Get-Project

$file = $project.ProjectItems.Item("Shell\Launcher.exe")

# set Build Action to None
$file.Properties.Item("BuildAction").Value = 0

# set Copy to Output Directy to Copy if newer
$file.Properties.Item("CopyToOutputDirectory").Value = 2
```

Comment: What is `$project`? What type of object is it?

Comment: is the csproj file - C# project file, (msbuild script)

Comment: So is it an object? A string? Is this whole thing wrapped in a function?

Comment: yes it is an object not a simple type

Comment: You're not doing a great job of answering what I've asked you...! What *type* of object is it? Where's the rest of the code? You can't have a standalone `param` block

Comment: sorry, I think I've figured it out - I'm new at this....

Answer (score 1):

The answer I found is as follows:

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

# $project = Get-Project

$shellFolder = $project.ProjectItems.Item("Shell")
$file = $shellFolder.ProjectItems.Item("Launcher.exe")

# set Build Action to None
$file.Properties.Item("BuildAction").Value = 0

# set Copy to Output Directy to Copy if newer
$file.Properties.Item("CopyToOutputDirectory").Value = 2
```

Comment: This is a completely different way to do this involving a targets file. It could be more attractive because you don't have to modify the item in the target project just to get it to copy. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25513519/517852).

Comment: this is a nuget install process not a pre\post build step

Comment: Yes and the effect is to install something that causes files to be copied to the build output, which can also be achieved with build targets. My suggestion is merely a different way to leverage the nuget install process. Nuget installs the build targets for you. It has the added "benefit" of not adding extraneous items to projects.

Comment: 'My suggestion is merely a different way' no it is not, this is a nuget package i am creating, pre\post build events are not relevant and completely wrong, your answer is just trolling for SO points - sad....