# Creating a nuget package containing a custom build step for .NET Core

Tags: msbuild, nuget, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

Is it possible to create a nuget package containing a custom build step (analyzing the generated assembly and automatically generating some metadata)? The target environment should be .NET Core with the new .csproj format (Currently using Visual Studio 2017 RC). Best case would be if this only adds a msbuild step and no dependency to the projects resulting assembly.

If seen that it should be possible with full .NET, but the documentation for msbuild and the new .csproj for .NET Core is a bit sparse at the moment.

Comment: I would think that the way to do this would be via the [built-in target imports](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25513519/517852). Not sure if it works for Core projects, but I don't see why it wouldn't. Much easier than mucking around with install scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nuget may execute "init.ps1" powershell script during installation if find it in your nuget package. But keep attention, that script support was modified  in Nuget 3.x:

> In Nuget 3.xx Powershell script support was modified to no longer execute install and uninstall scripts (install.ps1, uninstall.ps1), but init scripts are still executed.
>
> Additionally, running NuGet outside of Visual Studio at the command-line or on other operating systems cannot execute these Powershell scripts as they relied on Visual Studio automation. Powershell is in NuGet to provide a shim to allow for missing features to run inside of Visual Studio
> Powershell script support was modified to no longer execute install and uninstall scripts, but init scripts are still executed.

You can find more [here](http://blog.nuget.org/20151008/NuGet-3-What-and-Why.html) in "Powershell Install and Uninstall Scripts".

Comment: Thanks for the info. Do you know of any nuget package that adds a custom build step which could be used as reference? Possibly one for .NET Core?

Comment: I guess these .ps1 scripts won't be executed on MacOS then? Even if you have installed PowerShell Core that is. I'm using Jetbrains Rider as IDE and my feeling is that this aint supported.

Answer (score 8):

You can add MSBuild targets to a NuGet package in the "build" folder. The targets or props file name must match the package ID. When installed via "PackageReference" or packages.config, NuGet will automatically import the targets/props file into the csproj, so these files must be written as valid MSBuild code.

i.e. if your package was named "MyClassLibrary", you could have the following layout:

```
(package root)
    lib/
        netstandard1.3/
            MyClassLibrary.dll
    build/
        netstandard1.3/
            MyClassLibrary.props
            MyClassLibrary.targets
```

For example, see [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets/)  on NuGet.org or and its [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/tree/rel/1.1.0/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets) on GitHub. This package uses an MSBuild target to automatically generate an assembly attribute before the compilation step

Comment: would love more info on this! Can I use the `.targets` file to copy `Content` files from the package to the project that installed the package?